# What model is best for explaining variation?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, panel-data

I have been given two tasks 1.) predict future sales, 2.) explain what factors influence sales.

The way I am solving the prediction part is to use forecasting as taught by [Rob Hyndman](http://otexts.org/fpp2/). This seems straight forward to me.

What is more difficult is explaining why sales do what they do. I am guessing that this is best solved via longitudinal data analysis or a mixed model of sorts. Is this correct? Where can I learn more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referencing Hyndman, you might start with section 9.1
https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1 
on dynamic regression models.

These allow you to accommodate the autocorrelation in the data, while at the same time including other relevant information.

As usual, we have to be careful when we assign causality ("what factors cause sales"). A regression model is a START, but there are many ways that could be deceptive.

Comment: Yes, I understand that care is needed with causality. One question that has come up though is, how do I know when a forecast can't do much better. I have done a lot of forecasts, dynamic regression included and hit a wallt. When do I know I should stop? It seems like this question may not be answerable with forecasting methods.

Comment: There are various heuristics (using that term loosely): you are out of time. you are out of money/resources. the expected forecast error is adequate for management purposes in planning, the expected forecast error is lower than it's been in the past.  None of these are the answers you're looking for, I suspect. Perhaps someone smarter will chime in. :)